# Iterate over an array of hashtables, in order to get the key value stored in each hashtable

Tags: powershell

I have this piece of code , developed in PowerShell 4.0

```
$myArray=@()
$hT=@{}
$hTAux=@{}

@(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'" |Select-Object @{Name='TotalProcessorTime';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime}},Name,ProcessId,CommandLine |Where-Object { $_.TotalProcessorTime -ne $null }).ForEach({
    
    $o= new-object psobject -Property @{"ProcessId"=$_.ProcessId;"Name"=$_.Name;"TotalProcessorTime"=Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime};"CommandLine"=$_.CommandLine}
    $myArray.Add($hT.Add($o.ProcessId,$o))
    
})
```

The aim is to store, the values in array of hastables.

But, when trying to retrieve the info again to work with it, I dont know how I could access properly to the value stored in the hashtable

The piece of code below doesnt work:

```
$var=2

$c=(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'" |Select-Object ProcessId,Name,@{Name='TotalProcessorTime';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime}},CommandLine |Where-Object { $_.TotalProcessorTime -ne $null }).Length


while($var -ne $c){
    $hTAux=$myArray.GetValue($var)
        $hTAux.GetEnumerator() | % {$_.key} | Stop-Process

         $var++
    }
```

Shows me the error:

```
Exception when calling to "GetValue" with the arguments "1":   IndexOutOfRangeException
$hTAux=$myArray.GetValue($var)

CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Anyhelp to solve this issue would be appreciated

Many thanks

Regards

Comment: At this point, it would be better if you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish rather than asking why your code is not working. It looks like an over engineering of something that should be really simple

Comment: If you are wanting to retrieve a certain value from every Hashtable in the array, it can be as simple as `$HashtableArray.MemberName`, which produces a new array of only that member.  For example: `(@{A='A1';B='B1';C='C1'},@{A='A2';B='B2';C='C2'},@{A='A3';B='B3';C='C3'}).B`.  Similarly, to retrieve multiple values from each Hashtable, Foreach-Object can do the job - as in: `(@{A='A1';B='B1';C='C1'},@{A='A2';B='B2';C='C2'},@{A='A3';B='B3';C='C3'}) | Foreach-Object {$_.A, $_.B}`.